# How can I maximize efficiency of strings by only loading what the user needs?

Tags: c++, performance, memory

I am writing a program that has a setup something like this:

```
struct element {
    std::string two_very;
    std::string long_strings;
};

struct set {
    std::string name;
    element e1;
    ...
    element e12;
};


class myClass
{
    public:
        set *which_set;
};

set set1, set2, set3, set4;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    myClass stuff;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        std::string choice(argv[i]);
        if (choice == set1.name) {
            myClass.which_set = &set1;
        } else if (choice == set2.name) {
    }
}
```

These strings are very long, and I don't want them all to be in memory at once. However, the user can only use one of the `set` structs at a time, so is there a way to load only the one that the user requires?

Comment: _'These strings ...'_ which ones in particular?

Comment: This code snippet tells very little about the exact nature of the strings and sets so I can't give a really specific solution, but I would guess that you can write the long strings to their own files and read them in when the user requests them.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The strings used in the `element` struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the strings in a file and actually read the contents only if they are requested.

More precisely, turn your struct into a class and remove the member variables. Give it instead two member functions: `GetString1()` and `GetString2()`. And a private string member variable for a cached result + a private int member variable (in lack of a better mechanism for this concrete example) to remember which of the two strings the cache currently represents.

```
class element {
public:
    element();
    std::string GetString1() const;
    std::string GetString2() const;
private:
    int mutable m_cache_for_which_string; // made mutable for const methods 
    std::string mutable m_cache; // made mutable for const methods
};
```

When `GetString1()` is called, you open the file which contains the first string if it's not in the cache already; same for `GetString2()` with the second string. You remember either of the strings by storing it in the `m_cache` member variable.

```
std::string element::GetString1() const
{
    if (m_cache_for_which_string != 1)
    {
        std::ifstream is("file1.txt");
        // ...
        m_cache_for_which_string = 1;
        m_cache = file_contents;
    }
    return m_cache;
}

std::string element::GetString2() const
{
    if (m_cache_for_which_string != 2)
    {
        std::ifstream is("file2.txt");
        // ...
        m_cache_for_which_string = 2;
        m_cache = file_contents;
    }
    return m_cache;
}
```

Of course, the constructor needs to initialize `m_cache_for_which_string`:

```
element::element() :
    m_cache_for_which_string(0), // neither
    m_cache()
{}
```

And the code for reading the files should not be duplicated.

This whole trick makes sure that only one string is in memory at the same time, while providing an interface which hides these details. Return-value optimization (RVO) should make sure that returning the strings by value does not hurt performance (otherwise, when your measuring says that RVO doesn't work, you can always return `std::string const&`, measure again and keep it if it's faster).

Here's one final hint: you may want to read more about `std::map` and use it instead of the approach with the "set" struct having a "name" member variable.